# JQuery selector return undefined

Tags: jquery, attributes, selector, undefined

I am doing a news feeds like thing that rotate news after 7 sec.
I am using Jquery functions `$().slideUp()` and `$().slideDown()`.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id='F1' class='Nouvelles' style='background-image:url(../ImagesAnnonces/google_chrome.png); background-size:contain;'>
    <h2>test</h2>
    <p>test</p>
</div>
<div id='E2' class='Nouvelles' style='background-image:url(../ImagesAnnonces/images.jpeg); background-size:contain;'>
    <h2>test</h2>
    <p>test</p>
</div>
<div id='F3' class='Nouvelles' style='background-image:url(../ImagesAnnonces/); background-size:contain;'>
    <h2>test 2 FR</h2>
    <p></p>
</div>
<div id='F4' class='Nouvelles' style='background-image:url(../ImagesAnnonces/asdfgfhjkl.jpeg); background-size:contain;'>
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Here is what I have done so far:

```
//This is just a AJAX call that generate all the '.Nouvelle' which translate from french to news.

$(document).ready
        (function(){
            $.ajax(
            {
                url:"handlingPub.php",
                type:"GET",
                dataType:"text",
                contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
                success:function(code_html, status)
                            {
                                $("#divPub").append(code_html);
                                $(".Nouvelles").css(
                                    {
                                        height:"90px",
                                        display:"none",
                                        padding:"0px",
                                        margin:"10px",
                                        overflow:"hidden",
                                        border:"solid white 2px"
                                    });
                                $('.Nouvelles[id^="F"]:lt(1)').css("display", "block");
                                $(".Nouvelles h2").css({padding:"0px", margin:"0px"});
                            } 
            });

//the problem seems to be here...
//Get the first id
            var id = $('.Nouvelles[id^="F"]').first().attr('id').substring(1);
            alert(id);//This return 'undefined'...
//Every 7 sec.
            var int = self.setInterval
            (function(){
                var max = 0;
                //Get the number of news (I know I could use size() or length I will change it later)                   
                $('.Nouvelles[id^="F"]').each(function(){max++;});
                if(max > 1)//If there is more than 1 news
                {                       
                        $(".Nouvelles[id=F"+id+"]").slideUp();//slide it up
                        if(id >= max)//If the id of the news is bigger than the last one set it to the first
                        {
                            id = $('.Nouvelles[id^="F"]:first').attr('id').substring(1);
                        }
                        else//else go get the next
                        {
                            id = $('.Nouvelles[id^="F"]').next('.Nouvelles[id="F'+id+'"]').attr('id').substring(1);
                        }

                        $('.Nouvelles[id="F'+id+'"]').slideDown();//slide the next news down
                }
            }
            , 7000);
        });
```

Each '.Nouvelles' have unique IDs That either start with 'F' for french or 'E' for english.
I want to rotate and display ONLY the french ones for now.
French and English news will alternate in a random pattern. So the next sibling of 'F1' could some day be 'F2' or 'E2'.

The problem I am having is with this line here:

```
//the problem seems to be here...
//Get the first id
            var id = $('.Nouvelles[id^="F"]').first().attr('id').substring(1);
            alert(id);//This return 'undefined'...
```

I cant get the id. If I `alert($('.Nouvelles[id^="F"]').first())` it return a object.
But If I `alert($('.Nouvelles[id^="F"]').first().attr('id'))` it return undefined.
How can the id be undefine if in the Jquery selector I specificly ask for the element with an ID that start with 'F'???

does some one know where I am wrong??

Comment: the `attr()` function already returns the value of the first element in a set, so the `first()` call is not needed. But this should be irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: Are you adding the items in the ajax call?  If there are none on the page on `ready`, you would get a jQuery object that would be contain no elements but would alert an object and have no `id` attribute.  Do a `console.log($('.Nouvelles[id^="F"]').first().attr('id'))` and examine the object.  `alert` should not be used for debugging.

Comment: Your right @Schleis I am adding the items in my AJAX call and it does make more sense now. I am so shame I think I am just gonna lay down here and die XD :D thank you very much! Post your comment as an answer I'll give it a check mark!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are adding the items in the ajax call, your selector is not getting any elements on `ready`.

You would get a jQuery object that would be contain no elements but would alert an object and have no id attribute.

Do a `console.log($('.Nouvelles[id^="F"]').first().attr('id'))` and examine the object. alert should not be used for debugging.